# Rails Migrate data to mysql workbench GUI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, mysql-workbench

So I am trying to migrate my local database to the MYSQL Workbench database gui on my mac.

In my rails app:
*config/database.yml*

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: root
  port: 3306
development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3
```

My guess is that I need to change the path for `database`. I've already changed the `adapter` from `sqlite3` to `mysql`but i'm sure there is more configuration needed here...

What are the necessary steps to connect MYSQL Workbench to my rails application so I can manage my tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what needed to be done.

In *database.yml*, I changed the database in my development environment to some generic name `demo_development`:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: root
  port: 3306
development:
  <<: *default
  database: demo_development
```

dumped my existing database in *development.sqlite2*  then ran `rake db:create` then migrated my database `rake db:migrate` and that's it, I took a look at MYSQL Workbench gui and the tables were there.

Easy ;)

Comment: This helped. Thanks!